# Jimp: getting rgb color of pixels from 24-bit bmp

Tags: node.js, bmp, jimp

I have a 24-bit bmp file that I want to get the rgb values for the pixels using [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) for node. If I open the image in GIMP and examine pixel 0,0 the rgb values are r: 45, g: 203, b: 203. However, if I use Jimp and the following code:

```
Jimp.read(fileToRead)
          .then(image => {
            console.log(Jimp.intToRGBA(image.getPixelColor(0,0)))
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
```

I get { r: 173, g: 200, b: 150, a: 255 }

By eye, r: 45, g: 203, b: 203 is the correct color. So what am I doing wrong? Do I need to use some option to tell Jimp it's 24-bit? Can Jimp read 24-bit? Internally it's using node mod bmp-js which supposedly can decode 24 bit. Am I missing some basic knowledge about bmp format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the actual image from which you are trying to extract the color info. Jimp has a write() method. For example:

Jimp.read(...).write('/tmp/out.png');

Then open out.png and inspect by yourself